# how to select 2nd button using selenium code if 3 buttons are same

Tags: java, spring, selenium

error when i select one of them

I have 3 button and i wants to select 2nd one using selenium testing java code

```
<p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="openMediaCreator=true">Add</button>
    </p>
    <p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="openMediaCreator=true">Add</button>
    </p>
    <p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="openMediaCreator=true">Add</button>
    </p>
```

i use that code to select 2nd button

```
public BasketDetailsObject addYoutubeVideo(String URL){
        try {
            getDriver().findElement(By.linkText("Add")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is Error on add Youtube Video"+e);
        }
        return getFactory().create(BasketDetailsObject.class);
    }
```

but i knw it does not works 
please give me wright code for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, you need ensure that you have three buttons otherwise the get(1) may fails or give the wrong button.

```
List<Webelement> buttons = getDriver().findElements(By.linkText("Add"));
buttons.get(1).click();
```

Comment: got an error There is Error on add Youtube Videojava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Comment: does your findElement returned object earlier? Have you checked? In this case findElements have not returned anything but of earlier one has returned then this should work.